# On which environments should it be possible to access the Swagger API documentation

Tags: swagger, environment

I want to add Swagger to automatically generate the documentation for the endpoints of my API built with .NET Core 3.1.

Is there any best practice regarding the environments (testing, integration, production, etc.) where it should / should not be possible to access the Swagger documentation page? E.g. only on production, only on non-production, etc.

Technically I can easilly set it in the code like

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AIR API (v1)");
    c.InjectStylesheet("/css/swagger/custom-swagger-ui.css", "all");
    });
}
```

Comment: It helps in testing, development environment for sure. But for production it depends on your requirement if you want to allow your users to view swagger documents or not. You can customize or restrict actions if you don't want to allow operations from swagger ui in production.